# Convert DateTime afterusing GetDate?

Tags: sql, datetime

This is for SI am trying to convert a DATETIME so it formats as "mm/dd/yy"

I need the "LastPaymnt_Date" to be greater than or equal to 31-which I've successfully set up below. Any help would be appreciated

This is what I have; it generates an "Incorrect syntax near CONVERT" error

```
SELECT D1_Name AS 'Debtor Name', FILENO, Balance, LPaymnt_Date AS 'Last Payment Date'
FROM MASTER
WHERE LPaymnt_Date>=GETDATE()-31 
CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE, 101
AND(Forw_no>= 340 AND Forw_no <=348)
OR Forw_no =831
ORDER BY D1_Name
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing `AND` before the `CONVERT`.  Try closing the parenthesis after `CONVERT` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `CONVERT` in the `WHERE` clause. You want it in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT D1_Name AS 'Debtor Name', FILENO, Balance, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LPaymnt_Date, 101) AS 'Last Payment Date'
FROM MASTER
WHERE LPaymnt_Date>=GETDATE()-31 
AND(Forw_no>= 340 AND Forw_no <=348)
OR Forw_no =831
ORDER BY D1_Name
```

See here for more:
[SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: Your problem is not necessarily solved.  Subtracting an integer from GetDate() means that your sql is still taking the time portion of GetDate() into account.  That might not be your intent.  Also, you will always get the record for forw_no = 831, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D1_Name AS 'Debtor Name', FILENO, Balance, 
       LPaymnt_Date AS 'Last Payment Date',
       CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 101) As FormattedDate
FROM MASTER
WHERE LPaymnt_Date >= GETDATE()-31 
 AND ((Forw_no>= 340 AND Forw_no <=348) OR Forw_no =831))
ORDER BY D1_Name
```